# $\underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega') \leq \underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega),\; \forall \omega'?$

Tags: probability-distributions, inner-products, operator-algebras, supremum-and-infimum

I have a question:
Is it true that
$$
\underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega') \leq \underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega),\; \forall \omega'
$$
where the elements of the vector $\omega$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{i} \omega_{i} = 1$.

**Context:**
I was reading the mathematical proofs of the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08342.pdf on multi-objective reinforcement learning and, on **page 16 in the Appendix**, I stumbled across the proof of the **theorem 2**.
For this theorem, the authors defined a pseudo-metric over the space of action-value functions $Q(s, a, \omega)$, where $s$ and $a$ are respectively the state of the environment and the action performed by an actor:
$$
d(Q, Q') = \underset{s, a, \omega}{\max}\; \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s, a, \omega) - Q'(s, a, \omega)\right)\right|
$$

Then, the goal is to show that the Bellman optimality operator $(\mathcal{T}Q)$ defined below is a contraction, i.e. that $d(\mathcal{T}Q, \mathcal{T}Q') \leq \gamma d(Q, Q')$:
$$
(\mathcal{T}Q)(s, a, \omega) = r(s, a) + \gamma \mathbb{E}_{s'\sim\mathcal{P}(s'|s, a)}\left[ \arg_{Q} \underset{a', \omega'}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot Q(s', a', \omega') \right]
$$

The authors were able to show that:
$$
(\mathcal{T}Q)(s, a, \omega) \leq \gamma\; \underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega') - Q'(s', a', \omega')\right)\right| = \gamma d(Q, Q')
$$
completing their proof.

**My Problem:**
My problem is in the equality saying $\underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega') - Q'(s', a', \omega')\right)\right| = d(Q, Q')$. Indeed, given the definition of the metric $d$ and since we have $\omega'$ as argument to the functions instead of $\omega$, I am thinking that the equality is false and that we have instead:
$$
\underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega') - Q'(s', a', \omega')\right)\right| \neq \underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega) - Q'(s', a', \omega)\right)\right| = d(Q, Q')
$$
which would not be good for the proof.

**My solution:**
To make sense of the proof, I am proposing that maybe there is an omitted step where we would need the following relation:
$$
\underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega') - Q'(s', a', \omega')\right)\right| \leq \underset{s', a', \omega}{\max} \left|\omega^{\top}\cdot \left(Q(s', a', \omega) - Q'(s', a', \omega)\right)\right| = d(Q, Q')
$$
However, I don't know if such a relation is even valid, hence my question! My intuition tells me that the relation is true and that $\underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega') \leq \underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega),\; \forall \omega'$ is always valid, but I have no idea how to prove that, making me seriously doubt my intuition.

**Summary of my questions:**

(1) Is the relation $\underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega') \leq \underset{\omega}{\max}\; \omega^{\top}\cdot F(\omega),\; \forall \omega'$ always true? And how can I show mathematically whether it is true or not?

(2) Am I right to assume that the proof is only valid if the above relation is true and used, i.e., that there is a problem in the original proof as given in the paper? Or did I miss something?

P.s.: I know that any person who wants to answer would still need to go to the paper, as not all details are necessarily included above. At first, I wanted to include every single details about the context, but then I found it would be rather lengthy. I hope that I can still get some help on the matter. Thank you!